# Use Boost Serialization Library in VC++ 2010 Project

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compilation

i've downloaded the latest version of Boost Package (1.45) and I would use only the serialization library in my VC++ 2010 project. I tried to understand how can i compile that library and use it but i don't understand... Can someone help me to compile and use the serialization library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specifically require Boost 1.45 (or 64-bit binaries), you can get the pre-compiled boost library installers from Boostpro (the professional consulting wing of boost.org): http://www.boostpro.com/download/

If you do need to build 1.45, you will need to follow the instructions for a simple binary build:

From: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source

Get the source code, unzip it somewhere, open a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt, and navigate to that directory, and type in these commands:

(the '>' means the prompt)

```
> bootstrap
> bjam
```

Comment: ok i compiled the boost libraries and i have a bunch of .lib files, now should I only include the serialization lib in my project and use it?

Comment: @Stefano, yes, you should be able to just make your project link against libboost-serialization...whatever the full name is. And in your source code, follow stuff from the boost serialization tutorial: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Note that you don't need to explicitly link to the libraries with visual studio.  You only need to make sure that visual studio knows where to find the headers and libs and then include the appropriate headers.  Boost headers use special MicroSoft black magic to automatically link to the libraries.

Comment: mmm, I'm having an error... after the successful compile i set the include and libraries path and infact I can use the boost features but when I try to compile I have an error regarding the file of the library that does not find... the file has a -gd in the filename but in the boost directory i have the same file without that word. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Stefano: That probably means that you built the boost libraries in release mode, but your project is built in debug mode. Try building your project in release mode. (you should probably also build boost in debug mode, it will come in handy)

Comment: @Icebone1000 What version are you attempting to build?

Comment: 1.50, but nevermind, I was in the specific library directory, now I see its in the root one, its compiling